# Finding sum of values in a column

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, oledb

I am trying to find sum of values in a column using a condition but the result am getting is null am not sure of where the problem is coz i have tried running the sql database access but and it works but when i it at in the progam it does not work

So i need assistance on this one

The code is below

> Blockquote

```
  p.Query="SELECT SUM(income) FROM Emp_income  WHERE username ='" + frmlogin.username + "'"; 
            using (IDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(p.Query, p.Con))

            {
                object answer=command.ExecuteScalar();
                lblincome.Text=Convert.ToString(answer);
            }
```

Comment: You need to put a breakpoint to see if there's a value on the frmlogin.username but I am guessing there's not  because you are accessing the whole control. Try replacing it with frmlogin.username.Text to access the text inside that control.

Comment: You have ```'``` that you have misplace at the end of your first line. Change ```"'``` by ```'"``` But I don't konw if it's just something that came when you copy-pasted?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Username is a public static  variable that keeps the username of the person who has logined in and it is initialised in another form if a person wants to check there total income while still logged in they will there is a button which executes a method for the sum sql and only the records with income corresponding to the username should be added

Comment: There is no error message but it is returning nothing yet there should be something

Comment: I'd start by reading about the infamous "SQL Injection": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216107/what-is-sql-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add try/catch block to ExcuteScalar() for error message, for connection oriented ADO.Net  you have to Open connection before executing the command like con.Open()

Comment: It has worked it was because i did not open connection thanks everyone